# 401 Unauthorized with Ionic 5 + Angular 9 with POST request

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, http-post

I am making a post request in the following function:

```
addPlace(title: string,description: string, price: number) {
const newPlace = new Place(Math.random().toString(), title, description, 'https://i.insider.com/5d0150e06fc9200b5a05f042?width=1136&format=jpeg',price, this.authService.userId );
return this.http.post('https://hotelapp-2011f.firebaseio.com/offered-places.json', { ...newPlace, id:null}).subscribe(response => {
  console.log(response);

});
```

But I am getting a 401 Unauthorized error:

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 401, statusText: "Unauthorized", "https://hotelapp-2011f.firebaseio.com/offered-places.json", ok: false, …}
error: {error: "Permission denied"}
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message: "Http failure response for https://hotelapp-2011f.firebaseio.com/offered-places.json: 401 Unauthorized"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 401
statusText: "Unauthorized"
url: "https://hotelapp-2011f.firebaseio.com/offered-places.json"
__proto__: HttpResponseBase
```

Please help me solve this.

Comment: did it work for you?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

this is because your server is rejecting your request. probably because of authentication. check your headers that you are sending. are you sending the authentication token correctly? check them all and then try again.